# CSS Menu Help (IE Not working & Transation)

Tags: css

This menu is not working in any IE version. How can I get it working ?

I also would like to add transition, is there a way to add it so it opens slowly from top ?

http://tinyurl.com/7rxskdj

```
#nmenu {width:700px;}
#nmenu, #nmenu ul {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;}
#nmenu li {float:left;text-transform:uppercase;margin-left:45px;position:relative;}
#nmenu li.frst {margin:0;}
#nmenu ul {width:100px;display:none;position:absolute;top:30px;}
#nmenu ul li {width:100px;float:left;background-color:rgba(122,202,222,0.5);margin:0;padding:0;}
#nmenu li a {font: bold 11px/30px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;text-decoration:none;color:#939598;}
#nmenu li:hover ul {display:block;}
#nmenu li > ul {top: auto;left: auto;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide a doctype, so IE renders it in [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html). Use valid [HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE html>`)](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#the-doctype) or [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.2). Transitions are a little bit harder, as you need specific values to animate a CSS property. You could instead animate the `opacity` with `transition: opacity 1s ease`.

See also:

- [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org)
- [CSS Transitions Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)
- [CSS transitions - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about IE compatibility with CSS-only, but I am sure it will work using jquery... here is simple code:

```
$('#nmenu li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});​
```